# Git Precommit hooks for angular 9 application

Tags: angular, git, githooks

Here is my pre-commit file code which I have taken from https://gist.github.com/linhmtran168/2286aeafe747e78f53bf but every time it returns same `COMMIT SUCCEEDED`.

Here is the linting failure picture [image: linting failure picture]

`ng lint` having an issue but still how It can succeed. It should return validation fail message and commit should not be done but struggling with it.

Please will be much appreciated

I seen [Adding precommit hooks with Husky without pushing addition to git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46581101/adding-precommit-hooks-with-husky-without-pushing-addition-to-git) but not so helpfull.

Answer (score -1):

The linked gist has a bug: it uses `#!/bin/sh` as the shebang but it uses bash syntax `if [[ "$STAGED_FILES" = "" ]]`. To fix the bug change the shell to `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

Also my advice is to add `set -e` at the beginning so the shell fails at every error:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
```

Comment: I tried all above solution but then there is no any reflection of that file seems all goes like before when there was not pre-commit file.
please assist.
and there is code 

STAGED_FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".jsx\{0,1\}$")

so should i change .jsx  to .ts ?